# Return single variable (not list) multiple times to function from second function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

I have first function which is not possible to modify or change! It displays value of the variable (`main_index` field which cannot be the list, tuple, dictionary etc. It is simple just a variable and must remain as it is)

That function triggers second function which can return multiple values so the idea is to somehow display those multiple values one by one, but not putting them into the list or dict. etc. Second function can be changed in any way.

Code is the following (please take into account that first function cannot be modified in any way, I am just simplifying it here).

```
def not_changeable():
    value_to_check='7.1'
    main_index=generate_index(value_to_check)
    print (main_index)

def generate_index(index):
    dictionary={'7.1.1':{'value':'1'},'7.1.2':{'value':'2'},'7.100.3':{'value':'3'}}
    filtered_dict={}
    concatanatedIndex=index+'.'
    for k in dictionary.keys():
        if concatanatedIndex in k:
            filtered_dict[k]=dictionary[k]
    print (filtered_dict)
    for indx in filtered_dict:
        return (filtered_dict.get(indx).get('value'))

not_changeable()
```

As output I am getting one value (because of return function which ends the script)

```
{'7.1.1': {'value': '1'}, '7.1.2': {'value': '2'}}
1
```

But I would like to get values

```
1
2
```

without any modification on the first function.

I am aware that if I return list I will be able to display all values, but is it possible to display 1 and 2 without modifications on the first function?

Comment: `not_changeable` doesn't "give" you anything; it *prints* a string. It makes *one* call to `generate_index`, so you get *one* value that will have its `__str__` method invoked by `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning in a for loop is often not what you want, it might be better to build the data structure in the loop and then return later, or return the whole data structure as it is being built in a comprehension. Here you can return a string with newline characters instead of a value, like this:

```py
def generate_index(index):
    dictionary={'7.1.1':{'value':'1'},'7.1.2':{'value':'2'},'7.100.3':{'value':'3'}}
    filtered_dict={}
    concatanatedIndex=index+'.'
    for k in dictionary.keys():
        if concatanatedIndex in k:
            filtered_dict[k]=dictionary[k]
    print (filtered_dict)
    return '\n'.join(sorted(filtered_dict.get(indx).get('value') for indx in filtered_dict))
```

This will print

```
{'7.1.2': {'value': '2'}, '7.1.1': {'value': '1'}}
1
2
```

Breakdown of the last statement: `'\n'.join(sorted(filtered_dict.get(indx).get('value') for indx in filtered_dict))`:

- We use a comprehension to generate the data we are interested in: `filtered_dict.get(indx).get('value') for indx in filtered_dict` - this is actually a generator comprehension, but you can put `[]` to make it a list comprehension.
- Because we are iterating over a dictionary, and dictionaries not guaranteed to be in a certain order (though I believe this is changed with Python 3.6), I have added the `sorted` call to make sure `1` comes before `2`.
- To turn an iterable (like a list) into a string, we can use the string method `.join()`, which creates a string by joining together the elements in the list and puts the string in between each one. so `'-hello-'.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` will become `'a-hello-b-hello-c'`.

Actually a simpler way to build the return string would be to iterate over dict.values() instead of the actual dict. And if we are using python version > 3.6 we can skip the `sorted` call, so the return simply becomes: `return '\n'.join(v.get('value') for v in filtered_dict.values())`.

But a better design might be to return the values in a dictionary and print them in a specific format in a separate function that is only responsible for display.

Comment: But I am still confused how does this work :-) Can you please provide additional explanation? "Here you can return a string with newline characters instead of a value" Can you please explain why did you put new line character '\n' and did the join and why did you do sorting? I am really totally confused

Comment: I will add some explanation :)

Comment: Great work!  I am just confused with everything left from "filtered_dict" in your last line :-) Amazing really

Comment: @bananfish can you please provide additional explananation

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the `generate_index` function to return a generator, aka something you can iterate over (note the last line in the code below).

You can read up on generators [here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) or see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator)

```
    dictionary={'7.1.1':{'value':'1'},'7.1.2':{'value':'2'},'7.100.3':{'value':'3'}}
    filtered_dict={}
    concatanatedIndex=index+'.'
    for k in dictionary.keys():
        if concatanatedIndex in k:
            filtered_dict[k]=dictionary[k]
    print (filtered_dict)
    for indx in filtered_dict:
        # change from return to yield here to create a generator
        yield filtered_dict.get(indx).get('value')
```

Note that by calling this `generate_index`, you were already kind of shooting for a generator! Then you can call the result in your other function like so:

```
main_index=generate_index(value_to_check)
for index in main_index:
    print(index)
```

Hope this does what you want

Comment: I mentioned that I cannot change first function. Unfortunately your code does not work since I am getting     not_changeable()
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax